# Django Detail View Running 2x Number of Necessary Queries

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm new to django and I've been up half the night trying to figure out why this view is running two sql queries each for profile and for points. According to Django debug tools 7 SQL queries are run.

```
 1. SELECT...profile
 2. SELECT...points
 3. SELECT...profile
 4. SELECT...points
 5. SELECT...django_session
 6. SELECT...auth_user
 7. SELECT...posts
```

I don't understand why profile and points are hit twice? The SQL stack trace for each time profile is hit and each time points is hit are the same:

SQL Stack Trace for Profile:

1./Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py in **call**(72)   return self.application(environ, start_response)

SQL Stack Trace for Points:

1. /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py in **call**(72)
   return self.application(environ, start_response)
2. /Users/jcarnegie/Documents/web/admin-site/userProfile/views.py in get_context_data(19)
   context["points"] = Points.objects.get(user_id = self.kwargs["pk"])

Here is my code:

```
class UserProfile(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'userProfile/story.html'
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["points"] = Points.objects.get(user_id = self.kwargs["pk"])
        context["posts"] = Posts.objects.filter(user_id = self.kwargs["pk"]).prefetch_related('tags')
```

And here is my template:

```
{% extends "core/base.html" %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block content %}
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-inner">
    <div class="story">
        <div class="story-left" id="left-story">
        <div class="img">
            <div>
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pic-3123/{{profile.pic}}" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <h1>{{ profile.fname }} {{ profile.lname }}</h1>
        <p>{{ profile.title }}</p>
        <div class="details">
        <div>
            <span>Points</span>
            <p>{{ points.total }}</p>
        </div>
            {% if profile.city and profile.state %}
        <div>
        <span><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></span>
        <p>{{ profile.city }}, {{ profile.state }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if profile.company %}
        <div>
               <span><i class="icon-briefcase"></i></span>
           <p>{{ profile.company }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div>
        <span><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
        <p><span class="muted">Joined on</span> {{ profile.dateJoined|date:"M d, Y" }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="story-right">
       <h3>Posts Made</h3>
       <div class="tab-content">
       {% if posts %}
          <ul id="contributionHolder" class="right-ul">
              {% for post in posts %}
              <li class="content-item" id="post_{{post.id}}">
             <h1 class="volk-font"><a href="{% url 'contributions:detail' post.url post.id %}">{{post.title}}</a></h1>
             <p class="volk-font limited-text">{{ post.description }}</p>
             <div class="tag-holder">
                  {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
              <a class="tag volk-font grey-button-flat" href="">{{tag.name}} </a>
                      {% endfor %}
                     </div>
           </li>                        
           {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% else %}
        <div class="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>{{ profile.fname }} has not made any posts.</div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The debug toolbar can show you a stack trace for each SQL query, which will show you the code that caused it to run.

Comment: I forgot to add that. The debug toolbar is showing the same SQL stack trace for each query. I added this information above. Thanks Alasdair.

Answer (score 0):

If city and state are foreign keys of your Profile model then you hit database each time these fields are called with your template tags  `{{ profile.city }}, {{ profile.state }}`. However you can optimise performance by caching it with `select_related()` method (Note that it's applicable to any model with foreign keys).

The simplest way is to set `queryset` attribute in your view instead of model attribute:

```
queryset = Profile.objects.select_related().all()
```

And check django docs on this topic for more details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/